# How to clear Drupal temporary folder?

Tags: 7, media, cron, files

I've done research and simply cannot find how to clear the images from the temporary folder on Drupal 7! I have a jQuery slider on my home page that pulls the five latest image files to display. I tried to upload a new logo through the edit theme but decided to delete it because it needed resizing. Now that logo file (but broken) is displaying in my slideshow and it's located under:

> "/system/temporary/styles/front_page_slideshow/temporary/Logo2.png"

I've tried everything and cannot find that folder and or how to clear it. I tried clearing all caches and running a cron job--no changes. Please help! I cannot have this issue on the production site.

***Edit**
I'm using Acquia Dev Desktop to run the site. Under "File System" I saw that my temporary drupal folder is located in my

> C:\Windows\Temp directory

. SO I went there and found and deleted the image file, and ran a cron job... but the broken image is still showing up as part of my slideshow.

Comment: Check under sites/default/files/your theme folder.

Comment: Drupal stores references to files in the `fil

Comment: Thanks Bala, deleted the file from there as well proceeded to run cron.php, back to normal now.